# Junit Test Bool Value

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

Hello Every One I Have This Method Which it Checks if the Input String Is Numbers only And Its Return True Or False 
I Want To Make A Junit Test For this method and Actually I Don't know how to test  Method Like This Can Any One Help And Thank You All.
My Method:

```
    private Boolean Check_Ean(String EAN_Ch)
    {      
    Long EAN;

    try 
    {
            EAN = Long.parseLong(EAN_Ch);
            return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a class in the test folder(located at the same path as main). Then you need to use their annotations to or either **Prepare** the information, **Test** and **Destroy** the information(usefull when you have DB connection opens or streams):

```
public class TestClass {
 @Before
 public void setup() {
 //prepare information
 }

 @Test
 public void testCheck_Ean() {
   boolean result = Check_Ean(...); 
   Assert.assertTrue(result);
 }

 @After
 public void destroy() {
  //if you need to "destroy" some info
 }

}
```

Comment: You can find more information in: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/

Comment: @MahmoudWizzo Mark as answer =)

Comment: I must Wait 5 Min To mark any answer 
I will Make it When i can 
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
tester = new CLASS_NAME();
assertTrue(tester.Check_Ean("5");
assertFalse(tester.Check_Ean("this is noot a Long");
```

You might be overthinking it. Also the Check_Ean method maybe could be static if you pass the Ean as a parameter rather than getting a class variable.